# Waiting for dynamically loaded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load-order

In my page body, I need to insert this code as the result of an AJAX call:

```
    <p>Loading jQuery</p>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery/core/jquery-1.4.4.js'></script>
    <p>Using jQuery</p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    </script>
```

I can't use `$.load()` since the document has already loaded, so the event doesn't fire.

Is this safe? If not, how do I make sure the jquery script has loaded before my custom, generated code is executed.

Comment: Check this related answer out: **[Load ordering of dynamically added script tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38840724/2247494)**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is pretty safe. Historically, `<script>` tags are full blocking, hence the second `<script>` tag can't get encountered befored the former has finished parsing/excuting. Only problem might be that "modern" browsers tend to load scripts asynchronously and deferred. So to make sure order is correct, use it like this:

```
<p>Loading jQuery</p>
<script type='text/javascript' async=false defer=false src='scripts/jquery/core/jquery-1.4.4.js'></script>
<p>Using jQuery</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
</script>
```

However, it's probably a better idea it use dynamic script tag insertion instead of pushing this as HTML string into the DOM. Would be the same story

```
var scr  = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    scr.src = 'scripts/jquery/core/jquery-1.4.4.js';
    scr.async = false; // optionally

head.insertBefore(scr, head.firstChild);
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `insertBefore` instead of `appendChild`?

Comment: Modern browsers only execute scripts asyncrounously or deferred if `async` and `defer` has been specified. `async=false` and `defer=false` is completely unnecessary in HTML. However, scripts that are dynamically created have `async` set to true by default, which is why you need the `scr.async = false;` in the second code sample. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

Answer (score 112):

Add an ID to your script file so you can query it.

```
<script id="hljs" async src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.0.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Then add a load listener to it in JavaScript

```
<script>
  var script = document.querySelector('#hljs');
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Note to others: the `async` attribute seems to be required for this to work (at least for me with a fairly small import and using Safari)

Answer (score 31):

```
const jsScript = document.createElement('script')
jsScript.src =
  'https://coolJavascript.js'

jsScript.addEventListener('load', () => {
  doSomethingNow()
})

document.body.appendChild(jsScript)
```

Will load after the script is dynamically added

Comment: Its not the best idea to append the element before set the 'load' listener because if it loads too fast (cache), 'load' event will be dispatched before attaching the listener.

Comment: @MarcosFernandezRamos - do you mean the script should be appended after the 'load' listener?

Comment: @Cansu, exactly

Comment: @MarcosFernandezRamos Event listeners run asynchronously. It won't run until the JS returns to the event loop.

Answer (score 19):

**Wait for multiple scripts to load**

The following helper loads multiple scripts only once and returns a promise:

```
async function cirosantilli_load_scripts(script_urls) {
    function load(script_url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if (cirosantilli_load_scripts.loaded.has(script_url)) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.onload = resolve;
                script.src = script_url
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
        });
    }
    var promises = [];
    for (const script_url of script_urls) {
        promises.push(load(script_url));
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
    for (const script_url of script_urls) {
        cirosantilli_load_scripts.loaded.add(script_url);
    }
}
cirosantilli_load_scripts.loaded = new Set();

(async () => {
    await cirosantilli_load_scripts([
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js',
    ]);

    // Now do stuff with those scripts.

})();
```

GitHub upstream: [definition](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/c926acd68d6c17292491ce1af1c19e0c7635055f/docinfo.html#L14) and [usage](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blame/c926acd68d6c17292491ce1af1c19e0c7635055f/README.adoc#L2154).

Tested in Chromium 75.

Comment: It's not working for me, unfortunately. I'm getting the error `load_scripts is not defined`

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

There is also new feature in `jQuery 1.6`. It is called `jQuery.holdReady()`. It is actually self explanatory; when you call `jQuery.holdReady(true)`, `ready` event is not fired until you call `jQuery.holdReady(false)`. Setting this to false will not automatically fire a ready event, it just removes the hold.

Here is a non-blocking example of loading a script taken from the documentation:

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("myplugin.js", function() {
     $.holdReady(false);
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/ for more information

Answer (score 5):

this works for me

```
function loadScript(sources, callBack) {
    var script      = document.createElement('script');
    script.src      = sources;
    script.async    = false; 
    document.body.appendChild(script); 
    
    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if(typeof callBack == "function") callBack(sources);
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the listener before appending the element to the DOM? I know that the loading will only start after you return from the function (due to the thread-safe nature of JS) but I feel more comfortable using only fully initialized objects.

Comment: For this to work in `header`? change `document.body.appendChild(script);` to `document.head.appendChild(script);`

Answer (score 3):

```
    new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for (var mutation of mutationsList) 
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') 
                Array.from (mutation.addedNodes)
                    .filter (node => node.tagName === 'SCRIPT')
                    .forEach (script => {
                        //Script started loading
                        script.addEventListener ('load', () => { 
                             //Script finished loading
                        })
                    })
    }).observe(document, { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the solutions didn't work. I wanted to programmatically click a link after a script has loaded the right click event for the link. Thus I had to work with timeout and loop:

```
<script>
  var ifrbutton = document.getElementById("id-of-link");
  if(typeof(ifrbutton) != 'undefined' && ifrbutton != null && window.location.hash == "#special-hash") {
    var i = 0;
    // store the interval id to clear in future
    var intr = setInterval(function() {
      if (ifrbutton.onclick!=null) {
        ifrbutton.click();
        clearInterval(intr);
        i = 200;
      }
      if (++i >= 200) clearInterval(intr);
    }, 300)
  }
</script>
```

Thus the solution could also be to check in intervals for certain functionality that the script brings with it... Set some secure end just in case the script gets never loaded... Works safely for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Ciro Santilli is excellent. I have improved it a little bit because I faced some issues.

I made a special form field based on CodeMirror editor. Since the script for the CodeMirror is huge, I load it only on demand by field initialization.

If the form has 2 such fields, the loading of the script is started twice merely at the same moment, since the first started script is not loaded yet, it is actually loaded twice, what is bad.

The functions MyNamespace.loadScript(script_url) and MyNamespace.loadScripts(script_urls) always return a Promise so that you can decide whether to use await or then.

1. If the script is already loaded, it returns a Promise that resolves immediately.
2. If the script is being loaded, it returns a Promise with interval observing that resolves if the script is loaded.
3. If the script was never loaded, it returns a Promise with loading script that resolves by loaded event.

The code:

```
MyNamespace.loadScript = function (script_url) {
    console.log("loading: " + script_url);

    if (!MyNamespace.loadedScripts) MyNamespace.loadedScripts = new Set();
    if (!MyNamespace.loadingScripts) MyNamespace.loadingScripts = new Set();

    if (MyNamespace.loadedScripts.has(script_url)) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log("already loaded");
            resolve();
        });
    }

    if (MyNamespace.loadingScripts.has(script_url)) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log("loading in progress");

            let interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (MyNamespace.loadedScripts.has(script_url)) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    console.log("waited until loaded");
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 200);
        });
    }

    MyNamespace.loadingScripts.add(script_url);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = script_url;

        script.onload = function () {
            console.log("actually loaded");
            MyNamespace.loadedScripts.add(script_url);
            resolve();
        };

        script.onerror = function () {
            console.log("load error");
            reject(new Error("Error by loading the script " + script_url));
        };

        document.head.append(script);
    });
};

MyNamespace.loadScripts = function (script_urls) {
    let promises = [];
    for (let script_url of script_urls) {
        promises.push(MyNamespace.loadScript(script_url));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Answer (score -3):

$.ajax and $.load are the same thing. You can use either.  If you put $.load in a script tag on the page it will fire when it loads just like $.ajax().

When it comes to waiting for a script to fire before you do something what Tomalak said is kinda true.  The exception is asynchronous calls. Javascript will make an AJAX call then continue running the script and when the AJAX call responds it will run the success/fail depending on what you tell it to do.

Now say you want your JS to wait for the return, with a single call it's pretty easy just wrap every thing in the success callback, or you could do it the cool way and use $.deferred. This allows you to make a bunch of ajax calls or one and then run some code only after the finish.

$.when & $.then are probably the best for this situation.

Any way what your are doing is safe.