# Webpack 4 doesn't load page in order

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, webpack-4

I've upgraded to webpack 4 for Rails. I use it with Vue.js 2. I also use chunks in my configuration. But since upgrading, I've noticed that the page load order is weird. The page loads HTML before styles and JS has been loaded, which is not what happened before. I've attached links to the videos for before and after to understand the issue better.

I've been looking in here and everywhere to find anyone with the same issue, but I couldn't...

[With Webpack 3(before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK8ni.jpg)

[With Webpack 4(after)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrGB5.jpg)

Here are my configuration files:

### Dev Config

```
const environment = require('./environment')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin =
  require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

environment.plugins.append(
  'BundleAnalyzerPlugin',
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
)


module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

### Env (shared) Config

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const vue = require('./loaders/vue')

const additionalConfig = {
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          minChunks: 3,
        },
      }
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.sass$/,
      use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }]
  },
  output: {
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
}

environment.config.merge(additionalConfig);

environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vue)

module.exports = environment
```

### Pack related to the page in the video

```
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/display.css';
import 'flexboxgrid/css/flexboxgrid.css';

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

// ElementUI Components
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import locale from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en';

// Custom Components
import TextSection from '../components/TextSection.vue';
import TopNavigation from '../components/navigation/TheTopNavigation.vue';

import { store } from '../store';

Vue.use(ElementUI, { locale });
Vue.use(VueCookies);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  mounted() {
    var selector = document.querySelector("#app");
    var errors   = selector.dataset.errors;

    if (selector) {
      store.commit('base_states/authenticate',
        JSON.parse(selector.dataset.signedIn)
      );
    }

    if (errors) {
      this.$message({
        dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
        message: JSON.parse(errors).join("\n"),
        type: 'error'
      });
    }
  },
  components: { TextSection, TopNavigation },
});

if (!app.$cookies.get('timezone')) {
  app.$cookies.set("timezone", DateTime.local().zoneName);
}
```

### Rails view for that page

```
#app{ data: { signed_in: "#{user_signed_in?}", errors: flash[:errors] } }
  .landing-top
    .row.banner
      %top-navigation{ ":user" => user, "logo" => logo }
      .row.start-sm.around-sm.middle-sm.center-xs.landing-hero
        .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-12
          %h1= t 'static.banner.headline'
          %p= t 'static.banner.subtitle'
          .actions
            %a.no-decoration{ class: "el-button el-button--success", href: "/events" }
              See upcoming events
        .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
          = video_tag("https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/vras-assets/product_preview_new.webm",
                      poster: preview_poster,
                      class: "preview-video", autoplay: "true",
                      muted: "true",          loop: "true" )
  .landing-body.site-padding
    .row.around-lg.middle-lg.middle-md.features
      .col-md-4.col-xs-12.feature-column
        = inline_svg 'icons/potion.svg', class: 'svg-icon'
        %text-section{ "title" => t('static.first_section.title_one'),
                       "text"  => t('static.first_section.text_one') }
      .col-md-4.col-xs-12.feature-column
        = inline_svg 'icons/map.svg', class: 'svg-icon'
        %text-section{ "title" => t('static.first_section.title_two'),
                       "text"  => t('static.first_section.text_two') }
      .col-md-4.col-xs-12.feature-column
        = inline_svg 'icons/unicorn.svg', class: 'svg-icon'
        %text-section{ "title" => t('static.first_section.title_third'),
                       "text"  => t('static.first_section.text_third') }
  .row.center-lg.center-xs.video-showcase
    .col-lg-10.col-md-10.col-xs-12
      = video_tag('https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/vras-assets/preview.mp4',
                  poster: 'meta_cover.jpg',
                  class: 'preview-video',
                  autoplay: 'true',
                  muted: 'true',
                  loop: 'true')
    .col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-xs-10{ style: "padding-top: 20px" }
      %h3
        = image_tag("bigscreen_logo.png", width: "250px")
        %br
        = t('static.third_section.title')
      %text-section{ "text"  => t('static.third_section.text') }
  .landing-body.site-padding
    .row.around-lg.middle-lg.middle-md{ style: "margin-bottom: 100px" }
      .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-xs-12
        %text-section{ "title" => t('static.second_section.title'),
                       "text"  => t('static.second_section.text') }
      .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-xs-12.first-xs.last-lg.last-md{ style: "text-align: center" }
        %iframe{:title => "Discord Widget", :allowtransparency => "true", :frameborder => "0", :height => "519", :src => "https://discordapp.com/widget?id=402246704252059648&theme=dark", :width => "320"}
  = render "footer"

= javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag 'landing_page'
= stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag 'landing_page'
```

#### Update

My research led me to believe its this issue:

> This is happening because you're bundling with style-loader, which puts your CSS as a string inside your Javascript bundle.
>
> So the HTML will render (very fast) while the browser is parsing your JS bundle (very slow). Towards the end of that bundle, the browser will find the module containing your CSS string. Then it'll parse that and apply the styles with Javascript.

I can't find a way to improve this, so for now I've extracted the CSS I need into Rails `app/assets` folder, to load outside of webpack and Vue. That fixed the pop-in issues to a degree, but I still feel like its the wrong way to go about it and is just a workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't quite get to the bottom of this, but I have found an interim simple solution to get back to the original webpack 3 behaviours, of JS/CSS blocking loading of the page, inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652265/how-to-run-vuejs-code-only-after-vue-is-fully-loaded-and-initialized)

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  ### Initialise Vue app
});
```

It forces to wait till window loads all the JS/CSS assets, before loading my Vue. This worked on all, but one page, as everything except landing page is built from Vue components only.

For landing page, I've adopted @Berto suggestion to delegate JS/CSS pack load to the head, with a yield. So now we are also blocking execution on the landing page as well. Combined, I am seeing exactly the same loading behaviour as before.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for a matter for making sure the stylesheet works properly add:

```
= content_for :head
  = stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag 'landing_page'
```

and then in the application layout (or main layout)

```
= yield :head
```

That will ensure that stylesheets are loaded **before** the DOM and it is ready when javascript comes into action.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help the issue. Whatever I put stylesheets in the head or not, they still seem to load out of order. I'd even say at the very end, from what I see

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your configuration with webpack3 injects css at the top of the generated html and webpack4 does it at the bottom. Try to move `= stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag 'landing_page'` to the top. I am not sure what css goes to the `landing_page` tag. It might be incomplete and the rest of the css is loaded asynchronously from js. Inspect the html code generated by webpack3 and webpack4 and check the list of generated css chunks and their load order.

Comment: I think it does load asynchronously. I already tried putting stylesheets higher up, but it didn't do anything at all. As a workaround, I've extracted critical CSS into rails stylesheets, so it loads outside webpack and Vue. But it still feels like it shouldn't be that way, what happens if I decide to have all my CSS in packs?

Comment: Check this note https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/v4-upgrade.md#upgrading-projects-with-custom-webpack-setups-that-use-only-the-view-helpers

Comment: I did see it and tried changing the `extract_css` to `true`, but haven't really looked well into that specific thing. I'll give it another look