# Preload page in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a NuxtJS static site containing static text, 1 PNG image (served from the local `assets` folder) and the [vue-particles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-particles) plugin.

Every time I visit this page, the page gets loaded in the following order:

1. The HTML loads
2. The PNG image loads progressively.
3. The [vue-particles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-particles) plugin loads 2 seconds later.

**What is the best way to show a loading indictor until the complete page is loaded?**
*For the loading indicator, I'm thinking about a fullscreen CSS overlay div.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run VueJS code only after Vue is fully loaded and initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652265/how-to-run-vuejs-code-only-after-vue-is-fully-loaded-and-initialized)

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: I know that Puppeteer do have some idle helpers, like "do some stuff if the network is clean for more than X seconds and no thread blocked". But I guess that `requestIdleCallback` is pretty much the same kind of method, that may be useful in your case: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback If it's not, exploring the "browser idle" may be a decent idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  1. Turn your loader ON at first
data() {
  loading: true,
},

// 2. Listen on `mounted` `hook` on `vue-particles` and turn OFF your loader:
<vue-particles @hook:mounted="loading = false"></vue-particles>
```

Comment: This will turn the loader OFF as soon as the vue-particles component is mounted. However, this does not take into account the loading time of the PNG, right?

Comment: No. In your order PNGs are on the 2'nd place. I thought you wanted to wait for the last part.

Comment: I want to wait until the complete page is loaded.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar issue, my page is rendering before pages are fully loaded and causing issues. But the answer I find finish loading after everything is implemented, but not after they have loaded in.