# javascript dynamically loading scripts and async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am probably making a rookie mistake.

**Goal**

I have a script `loader.js`, where I want to supply a set of javascript files intended to manage component shape, size, position, etc.

The file is like this:

```
const loadScript = (FILE_URL, async = true, type = "text/javascript") => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
            scriptEle.type = type;
            scriptEle.async = async;

            //scriptEle.async = false; // i tried with this line as well.
            scriptEle.defer = true;

            scriptEle.src =FILE_URL;

            scriptEle.addEventListener("load", (ev) => {
                resolve({ status: true });
            });

            scriptEle.addEventListener("error", (ev) => {
                reject({
                    status: false,
                    message: `Failed to load the script ＄{FILE_URL}`
                });
            });

            document.body.appendChild(scriptEle);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};





$(document).ready(function () {

    setTimeout(proceed, 1);               // wait for the document to be fully ready.


});




async function proceed() {

    await loadVars();              // Load variable definitions
    await loadComponents();        // load component definitions 
    await make_components();       // and populate them

}


function make_components() {

    switch (monitorType) {         // monitor type should be defined once loadvar executes (and console.log agrees) 

        case 1 :

            addMobileHeader(wfull, hfull * 0.1);
            addMobileHeroBlock(wfull, hfull* 0.7);
            break;

    }

}



function loadVars() {

    loadScript("variables.js").then( data  => {
        console.log("Variables: Script loaded successfully", data);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err);
    });

}


function loadComponents() {

    loadScript("components_mobile.js").then( data  => {
        console.log("Components (mobilephone): Script loaded successfully _ mobile", data);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err);
    });



    loadScript("components_wide.js").then( data  => {
        console.log("Components (widescreen):Script loaded successfully _ wide", data);

    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err);
    });


}
```

**Problem**

Of course, `make_components()` is triggered before `loadVars` completes execution.

**Attempt to solution**

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881621/javascript-waiting-for-dynamically-loaded-script-to-be-ready),I thought that since `variables.js` is added first, it will be executed first, before the next (deferred) file, `components_mobile.js` is loaded and executed.

And only after all that is done, then the `make_components` function will execute, and will find all the definitions in `loadVars` file.

I know that I can make a call the next function directly in the `.then` part, like

```
loadScript("variables.js").then( data  => {
            console.log("Variables: Script loaded successfully", data);
          //call next function here
        })
```

But that will create a hell of chained function very hard for me to debug.

**Question**

Is there a way i can force the JS engine in chrome/ firefox to wait while one script is fully loaded and executed? Thank you.

**EDIT** : Without third party libraries, if possible please.

Comment: reason you are reinventing [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/)?

Comment: @epascarello did not know about it. Ill check. Also I want iwithout third party stuff if possible.

Comment: Dynamic imports have been [available for a few years now and are widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import). Even if you stick to what's strictly available in browsers you're *still* re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @JaredSmith page not found

Comment: Using your way, requirejs, or import, you are going to have to deal with promises.

Comment: Should just be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Comment: @Sean edited the link, should work now. I apparently banged an extra key typing the close paren for the inline link. D'oh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loadVars` and `loadComponents` are implicitly returning `undefined`, so `await loadVars()` and `await loadComponents()` don't actually wait for anything. You'll need to return a promise.

If you prefer `.then` syntax, do:

```
function loadVars() {
  // added "return" on the next line
  return loadScript("variables.js")
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Variables: Script loaded successfully", data);
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

If you prefer `async`/`await`, do:

```
async function loadVars() {
  try {
    const data = await loadScript("variables.js");
    console.log("Variables: Script loaded successfully", data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

And make a similar change in loadComponents

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nicholas Tower. Indeed, the return promise is a good idea.

I asked chatGPT, and chatGPT gave this solution which is very close to Nicholas Tower.

*Define the loader function*:

```
/* ChatGPT solution */
function loadScript(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      // Script is loaded and executed
      resolve();
    });
    script.addEventListener("error", () => {
      // Script failed to load
      reject(new Error(`Failed to load script: ${url}`));
    });
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

Then *Invoke the loader function* :

```
/* wait for document to be ready*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(proceed, 1);                                     // After one second, after body is ready, fire the proceed event.
});




async function proceed() {

    await loadVars();                                           // await FOR loadvars to complete
    await loadComponents();
    make_components();                                          // not an await call. by now everything is ready.

}

async function loadVars() {

    await loadScript ("variables.js");                          // Load variable definitions

}

async function loadComponents() {

    await loadScript ("components_mobile.js");
    await loadScript ("components_wide.js");

}
```

note, that each call to `loadScript` itself is wrapped in another function. In order to achieve that multiple-wrapping, chatGPT says, that you need to make each layer of wrap an async function, and each wrapped function an await.

Then :

async function make_components() {

```
switch (monitorType) {

    case 1 :

        addMobileHeader(wfull, hfull * 0.1);
        addMobileHeroBlock(wfull, hfull* 0.7);
        break;

}
```

}

This works fine.