# Has anyone come across this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPaymentMethod' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I am currently using Stripe.js V2 and V3, and I need to use stripe.createPaymentMethod() method.
When I try to use the following code, I get an error, which is shown below:

```
      const {paymentMethod, error} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: this.refs.creditCardForm,
        billing_details: {
          name: 'Jenny Rosen',
        },
      });
```

The error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPaymentMethod' of undefined

By the way, I get the same error when I use JS instead of React:

```
     Stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: 'card',
        card: cardElement,
        billing_details: {
          name: values.payment.creditCardHolderName,
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        // handle result
      });
```

Any info / experience is appreciated.

Comment: You can do this, yes. I'd recommend contacting [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for their recommendation on how to best implement it.

Comment: taintedzodiac, when working with Stripe.js, have you come across the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPaymentMethod' of undefined
... or that error for any other function

Comment: That would mean that `stripe` hasn't been loaded yet. Usually means you are loading Stripe.js asynchronously and there's a race condition. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308908/waiting-for-dynamically-loaded-script

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this while creating unit tests for my component. I added a validation if(this.stripe) before calling createPaymentMethod and it fix the issue. Hope it helps.