# React - Converting HTML script tag to load an SDK asynchronously

Tags: html, reactjs, asynchronous, dom, sdk

Currently I'm trying to add snapchat to a site through their SDK

my current attempt, can't figure out how to convert their Dom script into a function to be called when my component is loaded:

```
export function snapchatSDK() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/create.js';
    document.head.append(script);
  });

}

class Platforms extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    snapchatSDK();
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <p> Share on Social Media Platforms</p>
      <h4>Snapchat<h4>
       <button 
         className="snapchat-creative-kit-share"
         data-share-url= urlTobeShared()
          >
         Share me 
       </button>

       <h4>Twitter<h4>
       <button>
         Share me 
       </button>

      <h4>Reddit<h4>
       <button>
         Share me 
       </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the doc's as well:
[snap doc](https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/tutorials/creative-kit/web)

Comment: Are you facing any issue? What is the exact problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example doesn't make it very clear what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe one of these will help you figure it out?

#### Option 1

Try the unoffical [snapchat npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snapchat). (no idea if the package does what you need, buy maybe you haven't seen it yet?)

#### Option 2

Load the script in your HTML

```html
<script src="https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/create.js" />
<script src="/path/to/your/bundle.js" />
```

If loaded before your components mount, it should pick up your HTML and do whatever it does

#### Option 3

Maybe try setting `async = false` on the script:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/create.js';
script.async = false
document.head.append(script);
```

Please see [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308908/waiting-for-dynamically-loaded-script). Key takeaway is:

> Scripts that are dynamically created and added to the document are async by default

Answer (score 2):

I think that the main issue is how you are trying to load the script dynamically. I am guessing that is what you want to do.
If so, there are several more steps. Here is a link to a comparative example that goes through some of them:
https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/articles/Declaratively_loading_JS_libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parcel2 or webpack4 (or create-react-app) then you could use dynamic import and most importantly without this [issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2358)

However, the code is simple

```
    import("https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/create.js").then(_snap =>
      setSnap(_snap)
    );
```

if you are facing that issue you could use

```
    import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ "https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/create.js").then(
      _snap => setSnap(_snap)
    );
```